# Responding to a (not really) rejected job position

Tags: rejection

I was wondering what kind of response I could send to this message. Have you any ideas, please. Thanks

"unfortunately, there are no persons in charge available in my department who could act as a caregiver for a bachelor thesis this year.
I checked all possibilities but I regret that I don’t have better news."

Comment: What is your actual question. What kind of response do you want to give?

Comment: Plus you could ask politely if they can think of any other departments or any other contacts they might have that you could approach - but that's just-in-case, don't expect a positive answer and don't get upset if you don't get a reply. However "a caregiver for a bachelor thesis" - that sounds like you want an academic supervisor? But even then 'caregiver' is an odd choice of word. Is this an academic position, or an industrial placement as part of your course?

Comment: Raoul Mensik: yes I just want  to reply to the mail.                                                                                                                         @Rup: academic position to concretise my last year Bachelor study. ok Thanks.                                                                                                                                                       Joe: Thanks. simple and correct.

Answer (score 2):

It's a rejection. Politely phrased, but it says "we can't use you." Move on to apply elsewhere.

Unless you think they have misunderstood what kind of position you are looking for. In that case, review your resume and cover letter to determine how they got the wrong impression and figure out how you can fix that.